# Sorting and matching two column with uneven sets of data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two columns like this:

Initial Table

[image]

COL-A and COL-B are coming from two different files. I have to do two things: a) match these two columns, b) find which data is missing. What I do, I insert a third column, COL-C, by adding VALUE(LEFT(B2,6)). Then I sort COL-A individually. After that, I sort COL-B and COL-C based on the value in COL-C. Then I deduct COL-A from COL-C in COL-D, move data manually to find the missing value. Finally, it looks like this.

Final Table

[image]

I work with these data every day. Numbers of data change daily, maybe today I will have 250 data, maybe the next day it will be 400 and this is a very important thing to remember. I was wondering if anyone can tell me how to get it done in a single click. I am willing to use VBA if needed. My Excel version is 2016. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like VLOOKUP will do the job nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not elegant, but will work without manual re-arrangement of COL-A or COL-B

In Col C, do as you thought, strip the first 6 characters of B

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(B2,6)),0)
```

Then in Col D use a VLOOKUP to identify the missing ID from column A

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:C,1,FALSE),"Missing")
```